# Cannot implicitly convert type T to List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic property in a class that declared like this below.

```
[XmlArray("SampleData")]
public T SampleData { get; set; }
```

When the `SampleData` property gets populated, it can sometimes actually be a list of `SomeObject` rather than a non list object.

The property above is being serialized along with other properties like this.

```
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
{
    var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    xml.Serialize(writer, this);
    context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(writer.ToString());
}
```

It errors out on the `xml.serialize` line with this error:

> There was an error generating the XML document
>
> Unable to cast object of type 'LongNameSpace.XMLResult`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LongNameSpace.Storage]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LongNameSpace.Storage]'

One idea that I thought might help with the above is to have a bridge property that would be like this in another class that would act as a bridge where I could then pass it into

```
[XmlArray("BridgeSampleData")]
public List<T> BridgeSampleData { get; set; }
```

However, I get a different error that looks like this when trying to stuff it into the bridge class and property.

> Cannot implicitly convert type T to List

So, my question is how to overcome either the first cast object error or if there is a way to convert a T to a List of T?

Comment: *"When the SampleData property gets populated, it can sometimes actually be a list of SomeObject rather than a non list object."* Shouldn't it be declared as a `List<T>` then instead of `T`? Otherwise, how would you store that list?

Comment: Have you tried the [DataContractSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=netcore-3.1) ? It works a bit different from the XmlSerializer.

Comment: The XMLResult class I'm utilizing can have something like this being passed in -  return XMLResult<List<DataStorage>>.Ok(storage);. When serializing to JSON, this isn't an issue but with serializing to XML it is.  So, a property of T can in reality be a List of T.